# Magento Cron throws error after upgrade from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.10 with php 7.2

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.9

Upgraded multistore Magento from from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.10 to be compliance with php 7. 
But now, if I turn on cache for Configuration [image]

Cron.php throws errors:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:952:"#0 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/Mage.php(356): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL)
#2 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php(47): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/log/enab...')
#3 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/Mage.php(550): Mage_Log_Helper_Data->__construct()
#4 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/Mage.php(814): Mage::helper('log')
#5 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php(234): Mage::log('Warning: simple...', 3)
#6 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/is/htdocs/wp12...', 383, Array)
#7 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(383): simplexml_load_string('";s:11:"script_name";s:61:"/is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/index.php";}
```

Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Isn't this programming related? Are all other magento issues tagged here with "magento" programming related?

Comment: This appears to be an issue with a program, but it's not about programming. Those are two different things. All questions on this site should be programming-related. Any questions that are tagged [magento] that aren't programming-related should also be closed.

Comment: there is an issue with the code. Workaround is programming related. Whats the problem?

Comment: You're not asking a programming-related question. It doesn't matter if there is a programmatic solution or not. You need to ask something specific about programming for it to be on-topic.

Comment: Thats solely your IMHO. I think I'm asking programming related problem.

Comment: Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It specifically requires that questions are about "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers". You're asking about an application, not a tool, so it seems to me that it's off-topic. So, it's not solely my opinion.

Comment: you can check here bit.ly/2R0wJFd

Comment: Thank you. But as I mentioned most recent PHP7.2 patch had been installed. I thought that probably due to libxml, but my hoster assured it had been installed with php7.2 .